# Question about text formatting using sed of awk

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, text-formatting

I want to format text using `awk` or `sed`.
I have text looking like,

```
H1 (dxfault)
H337 (Unxr)
H1106 (hast)
H1129 (h1129)
H1370 (hlan1370)
```

I want to remove the letter `H` and everything after the **first space**, and format numbers look like `1,337,1106,1129,1370`

I found two different `sed` options

First:

```
sed 'y/H/ /' #for removing H letter in front
```

Second:

```
sed 's/\s.*$//' #for removing everything after first break "space"
```

How can I combine these commands and add a comma after the numbers?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` to get the numbers only and `paste` to merge the lines with `,` as delimiter:

```
sed -E 's/^H([0-9]*).*$/\1/' file | paste -sd,
```

or `grep` and `paste`:

```
grep -Po '^H\K[0-9]*' file | paste -sd,
grep -o '^H[0-9]*' file |  cut -c 2- | paste -sd,
```

You can [exchange the linebreak with `,` with `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed), but imo `paste` is easier.

Comment: hi.. can you tell me why can't we use `or`(`|`) operator `sed -E 's/^H|\s.*$/\1/'` also what does `\1` and `()` mean?

Comment: You can't use `|`, because you want to match `^H` at the beginning and `\s.*$` at the end of the line which are two matches (not one or the other). `()` is used to group the matches and `\1` is a backreference to the first group in the replacement. See for example `sed -E 's/(^H)(.*)(\s.*$)/1:\1 2:\2 3:\3/' file` which uses 3 groups and backreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Or `sed`/`grep` using `tr`:

```
$ sed -E 's/H([0-9]+).*/\1/' file | tr '\n' ,

$ grep -o '[0-9]\+\s' file | tr -s '\n ' ,
```

- `tr '\n' ,` replaces newline with comma
- `tr -s '\n ' ,` replaces newline and space with one comma

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method

```
sed -e "s/H//g" -e "s/\s.*//g" filename | perl -pne "s/\n/,/g"| sed "s/,$//g"
```

output

```
1,337,1106,1129,1370
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Python too

```
import subprocess
import re
k=re.compile(r'\s.*')
u=[]
f=[]
l=open('l.txt','r')
for i in l:
    u.append(re.sub("H","",i).strip())
for m in u:
    f.append(re.sub(k,"",m))

print ",".join(f)
```

output

```
1,337,1106,1129,1370
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`, assuming that any characters may be used but there is only 1 space ....

```
sed -E "s/^H(.+) .*$/\1/g" filename | paste -sd,
```

I would rather opt for `grep` though which allows for any characters and extracts the match until the first space found

```
grep -Po "(?<=^H)[^ ]*" filename | paste -sd,
```